# How to create a menu to execute some bash scripts with a select loop?

Tags: bash

I have a very important project that needs a menu to execute some bash scripts. What happens is that this code works fine but doesn't get back to the menu after executing one of the options. Can you help me please?

```
#!/bin/bash
PS3='Escolha uma opção: '
options=("Cria condutor" "Cria passageiros" "Lista negra" "Atualiza condutores" "Stats" "Sair")
clear
select opt in "${options[@]}";
do
case $opt in
    "Cria condutor")
    echo "Insira o número de estudante: "
    read nestudante
        echo "Insira o primeiro e Último nome: "
    read nome
            echo "Insira a sua turma: "
    read turma
            echo "Insira o número de telemóvel: "
    read ntelemovel
            echo "Insira o seu e-mal: "
    read email
            echo "Insira o tipo de viatura (carro ou mota): "
    read tipo
            echo "Insira a marca do veículo: "
    read marca
            echo "Insira a matrícula: "
    read matricula
    exec ./cria_condutor.sh $nestudante $nome $turma $ntelemovel $email $tipo $marca $matricula
    break;;

    "Cria passageiros")
        exec ./cria_passageiros.sh
        ;;

    "Lista negra")
        exec ./lista_negra.sh
        ;;

    "Atualiza condutores")
        exec ./atualiza_condutores.sh
        ;;

    "Stats")
        exec ./stats.sh
        ;;

    "Sair")
        break
        ;;
    *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Use a `while` around your `select`. Also, quote your variables `exec ./cria_condutor.sh "$nestudante" "$nome"`.

Comment: You can use `read -p "Insira o número de estudante: " nestudante`

Answer (score 1):

You use `exec` to *replace* the current process with what you call.  Just strip the `exec` to create a subprocess instead, wait for its termination, and then continue with your script:

```
read matricula
./cria_condutor.sh $nestudante $nome $turma $ntelemovel $email $tipo $marca $matricula
break;;
```